# How do we analyse likelihood in a dataset?

Tags: classification, clustering, likelihood

I am working to analyze poverty rate using census data.

I have a huge dataset. I want to extract the likelihood from this dataset in order to create patterns for energy consumption.

What is the best approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: The notion of "likelihood" only makes sense under the context of a given model of some kind. Once you define a (or several) model(s), you can start to talk about the likelihood of your data under that model.

Comment: I am working to predict energy-consumption. I use census data to gather info about householder, poverty rate, demographic information .. This is what do you please by model.

Comment: Can you please explain more, based on this case ? or by giving any other example.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do? Why don't you start by parsing out what specifically you are trying to accomplish with your analysis, and we'll work from there instead of getting tied up in technical semantics like the definition of likelihood.

Comment: The approach I am trying to apply is, in order to predict energy consumption, I learn from people's behavior. I can't model it as counting predictive model. But I can use these patterns with to make sure whether they would. (Location - date- information (weather , demographic info .. ) - consumption), to help me predict in the future based on the patterns I am creating (That's why I am asking how can I make patterns or likelihood)

Comment: Just throwing some buzzwords (likelihood, clustering) won't solve a problem, you know. Just like using random tools won't help you build a house. The "best approach" is: **figure out what you want to do**, then choose your tools.

Answer (score 1):

To restate your problem: you have certain variables in your dataset that describe "households," and you are hoping to predict the energy consumption of households based on their metadata.

I would suggest you start by trying to a simple linear regression model (there are lots of other models you can try, but this is an easy one). I strongly suspect you will find the number of members of a household have a stronger effect on energy consumption than the average age of the household. If you are able to build a model that has a strong fit to your data, then you might focus your analysis on points with high residuals (large error terms, i.e. outliers to your model fit). You can consider these points "unlikely" under the description given by your model.

You suggested applying clustering. I'm not sure what you are hoping to accomplish with clustering, but it's not unthinkable that it could be applied here. The thing is, I suspect your data doesn't group into discrete clusters: instead, your points probably fall along a spectrum. To apply clustering, you are basically saying: "Most of the members of my data fall into a small number of categories, so I'm going to represent my data by those categories." You can verify this graphically. Ignoring location, you only have three dimensions. Throw together some plots and see if it looks like clustering might be reasonable. I suspect it won't be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your research question is to predict energy use based on household characteristics. In terms of modelling choice, I would go with OLS first because engery use is more likely to be a continuous variable than discrete in your data.

And clustering would help with precision. For instance, households living in the same location are likely to have similar unobserved characteristics that are not captured by the controls you put in the OLS. And I don't see the point of talking about likelihood at the moment.